# Is there any way to send email using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail-api

I have a static website which contains a static contactUs page. I want that use only javascript to allow users to use this website to contact with us. I have seen there is a Gmail oauth to do this but not find any sample code. Can someone tell me is it possible to do this in javascript ?

I tried this: [Sending EMail from my Javascript App via GMail API - mail appears in GMail sent list, but isn't delivered to destination email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946490/sending-email-from-my-javascript-app-via-gmail-api-mail-appears-in-gmail-sent)

and getting following exception in console:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=33434344.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.send&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay893566989&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000&response_type=token&gsiwebsdk=1&state=505139957%7C0.3440281612&authuser=0&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.R4vvmD-bxFg.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNqw3woMCdGPJ1k0Sr5vKTnVpzXbw does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: Add what you tried so far? (code).

Comment: question updated

Comment: Use the 'emailjs' library. [emailJS](https://www.emailjs.com)

Comment: Actually i am trying to implement using Gmail because it will be more easy that using same account i can reply back to customer on which i am receiving emails.